# Unexpected input type. Only archive types are supported, e.g., .jar, .zip, etc. Android

Tags: android, proguard

While generating release Apk I got the below error from progurd.

```
Unexpected input type. Only archive types are supported, e.g., .jar, .zip, etc.

/MyApp/app/proguard-project.txt, offset: 1765, line: 47, column: 14, Unexpected input type. Only archive types are supported, e.g., .jar, .zip, etc. 

How to fix this issue. anyone give suggestion.
```

Comment: did you find solution ?

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned on the docs, when you use Android Studio 3.4 or Android Gradle plugin 3.4.0 and higher, R8 is the default compiler for obfuscation.
R8 doesn't support some of the proguard config annotations.

more specifically, looks like the -injars -outjars doesn't accept your current configuration.

To disable R8, just use

```
android.enableR8=false
```

in your gradle.properties file

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code

Comment: won't this disable the R8 instead of fixing the issue?